# ReactJS + Flux - How to implement toasts/notifications?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactjs-flux, flux

I'm trying to understand Flux and Reactjs.

Consider a following, very simple scenario:

You have a form with few inputs. When user submits form,

```
ActionCreator.publishAnnouncement(this.state.announcement);
```

is called inside my form component. 
This is how the publishAnnouncement method looks like:

```
var publishAnnouncement = function (announcement) {
  AnnouncementAPI.publishAnnouncement(
    announcement,
    successCallback,
    failureCallback
  )
};
```

AnnouncementAPI is just a wrapper upon an AJAX http POST call. It takes two callbacks - on success and on failure.

And now: I need to show a notification/toast on the screen - indicating success or failure. 
**How would you do that in a Flux way?**

I was thinking about creating Notification component and rendering it inside my form. 
Like the following:

```
<Notification title={this.state.notification.title} message={this.state.notification.title} visible={this.state.notification.visibility}  // ?? onTimeExceeded ??     />
```

But how do I handle those callbacks? Should I create NotificationStore which listens for ANNOUNCEMENT_PUBLISHING_SUCCEEDED and ANNOUNCEMENT_PUBLISHING_FAILED events? In reaction to those events, store emits CHANGE event and thus my Notification updates.

But even if I do that, how should I instruct my Notification to show/hide? Or worse, to show up and hide after 2 seconds?

I've seen few components on [GitHub](https://github.com/pburtchaell/react-notification) and each of them uses refs etc, which I personally don't like.

To sum up:
**How would you implement this? Or maybe such project exists? If so, where can I find it?**

Comment: Facebook themselves talk about implementing notifications (user messages) in Facebook using React and Flux in their flux architecture initial video.

Comment: `refs` are the recommended way of implementing this. Sorry, your personality need to change ;-)

Comment: But shouldn't render be function describing a state of your component in a certain point of time? If so, then using such a component with refs totally breaks it.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum having Store for user notifications makes sense. Creating one just to fill the popup-component state - probably not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with having a store solely for notifications, especially if you want logic around showing/hiding notifications on timers, showing multiple notifications, etc.

There are two ways I would consider writing this:

1. Bind the NotificationStore directly to the success/failure callbacks you care about, like you mentioned in your question. Not sure what flux implementation you're using, so this will be pseudocode-y.

   ```
   class NotificationStore {
     constructor() {
       this.notificationId = 0;
       this.notifications = {};
       this.bindActionType(
         CLEAR_NOTIFICATION,
         this.handleClearNotification
       );
       this.bindActionType(
         ANNOUNCEMENT_PUBLISHING_SUCCEEDED,
         this.handleAnnouncementPublishingSucceeded
       );
       // etc...
     }

     handleAnnouncementPublishingSucceeded(action) {
       this.addNotification("Success!", { timeout: 2000 });
     }

     handleClearNotification(action) {
       this.removeNotification(action.notificationId);
     }

     addNotification(message, options) {
       const nextId = this.notificationId++;
       const notification = {
         message: message
       };

       this.notifications[nextId] = notification;
       this.emit("change");

       // if we specified a timeout, remove the notification
       // after the timeout expires.
       if (options.timeout) {
         setTimeout(() => {
           dispatch(CLEAR_NOTIFICATION, {
             notificationId: nextId
           });
         }, options.timeout);
       }
     }

     removeNotification(notificationId) {
       delete this.notifications[nextId];
       this.emit("change");
     }
   }
   ```
2. Specify the notifications you want in your action creators. This is more explicit but less centralized.

   ```
   var publishAnnouncement = function (announcement) {
     AnnouncementAPI.publishAnnouncement(
       announcement,
       (response) => {
         dispatch(ANNOUNCEMENT_PUBLISHING_SUCCEEDED, ...);
         dispatch(CREATE_NOTIFICATION, {
           message: "Success!",
           timeout: 2000
         });
       },
       (error) => {
         dispatch(ANNOUNCEMENT_PUBLISHING_FAILED, ...);
         dispatch(CREATE_NOTIFICATION, {
           message: "Failure!"
         });
       }
     )
   };
   ```

   In this case, the NotificationStore would look basically the same, but without binding to each and every success/fail action. In either case, I would have a single Notifications widget near the top of my component tree that rendered the list of notifications.

Comment: From my perspective, the 1st option is much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

In defense of refs (and as the author of the linked GitHub repo): Your stores could emit an event when they change, which would have a handler in the component. This handler would then trigger the notification via the ref. It is much less complex have your component handle the notification through refs instead of props.